# Position of JComponents using Netbeans GUI Swing Builder

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jpanel, jbutton

I'm developing a graphic interface using Java and Swing, and I'm having a hard time getting the JButtons to stay in their position while changing from one panel to another.

There are three buttons in a row aligned in the left bottom of each panel, all the panels the same size, but somehow they manage to change their position a little when I run the application (on the design preview they show up in the right place). It's getting a bit annoying. I'd appreciate any help

Comment: Change column 42 of line 137 from a '.' to a ',' and everything should be good.  OTOH if that does not work, try posting an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) and asking a specific question.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to do tabs? If you are, a `JTabbedPane` will do this much better than a button.

Since you are using the Netbeans GUI Builder, look at the options in the Component panel on the left. It has `Swing` tabbed panes and `AWT` panes if you really want.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer Jon. Tabs aren't actually what I was looking for, since the buttons are there for moving forward and backward through a bunch of pages. It's meant to be a tactile application to be displayed in some points for public use, so I decided I should put some big rounded buttons for best usability. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using a `LayoutManager`. Any of them work, but you should be using one. If everything is just slapped on the `JPanel`, then it will inevitably fail, always.

Comment: *"the buttons are there for moving forward and backward through a bunch of pages"*  Use a [`CardLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) for the other panels.

Comment: @AndrewThompson `CardLayout` wouldn't be very nice here. Once you get passed just a couple cards, the layout becomes very confusing. It could work temporarily though.

Comment: *"Once you get passed just a couple cards, the layout becomes very confusing."*  Not for me.  Each card is in its own `JPanel`, so the layouts can be specific to the content.  After they are all added to the layout, each one can be called by name.  Where are *you* getting confused?

Comment: I'm saying that the look of the GUI becomes cluttered, but I guess a tabbed pane wouldn't be any better.